# If $s\in (1/2, 1)$ and $[f]_s\le K$, does $||f||_{L^2}$ happen to be bounded by a constant depending on $K$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $s\in (1/2, 1)$ and $f\in H^s(\mathbb R^n)$. By definition, $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ and $[f]_s<+\infty$, where $[\cdot]_s$ denotes the Gagliardo seminorm.

Assume that there is a constant $K>0$ such that $$[f]_s\le K.$$

Is there any way to use this information to prove that there exists $c>0$, possibly depending on $K$, such that
$$\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)}\le c?$$

I mean, if I know that the Gagliardo seminorm of $f$ is bounded by $K$, does this give any information about the bound of the $L^2$-norm of $f$?

I am looking for some hint here [Hitchhiker's guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345), but I do not have success so far.

[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345): [Hitchhikers guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4345)

Comment: Do not delete your question immediately after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to future readers who might find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not true. The Gagliardo seminorm only measures the regularity part of the Sobolev norm and so cannot control the ``mass'' part of it. To construct a counter example I am going to use Proposition 3.4 from the paper in your question which provides a Fourier representation of the seminorm:
$$
[f]_s^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\xi|^{2s}|\mathcal{F}(f)|^2(\xi) \, \mathrm{d}\xi \, ,
$$
where $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ which I will assume w.l.o.g is zero inside $[-1,1]$ (if not I can always subtract it away and I am still left with an $H^s$ function because the integral will still be finite). Consider a bump function $\varphi$ which is nonnegative, compactly supported in the ball of size $1$ around $0$, and has integral one. Rescale it as follows $\varphi_{\epsilon}= \epsilon^{-1}\varphi(x/\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$ so that it has support in $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. Now consider the function $f_\epsilon = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(f) + \varphi_{\epsilon})$. We then have that
\begin{align}
[f_{\epsilon}]_{s}^2 = &\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\xi|^{2s}|\mathcal{F}(f_{\epsilon})|^2 (\xi)^2 \\
=& \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\xi|^{2s}|\mathcal{F}(f)|^2 (\xi)^2 + \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon|\xi|^{2s}|\varphi_\epsilon|^2 (\xi)^2 \\
\lesssim & K + \epsilon^{2s-1} \, ,  
\end{align}
where have used the fact that $|\mathcal{F}(f)|$ and $\varphi_{\epsilon}$ have disjoint supports, that $\varphi_{\epsilon} \leq \epsilon^{-1}$, and that $|\xi|^{2s} \leq \epsilon^{2s}$  on $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$. On the other hand the $L^2$-norm is given by
\begin{align}
\|f_{\epsilon}\|_{L^2}^2 = &\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\mathcal{F}(f_{\epsilon})|^2  (\xi)^2 \\
=& \|f\|_{L^2}^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\varphi_\epsilon|(\xi)^2 \mathrm{d}\xi \\
\sim & \|f\|_{L^2}^2 +\epsilon^{-1} \, .
\end{align}
Thus, if $s>1/2$ it is clear that one bound is stable while the other blows up. There is probably a simpler construction than this to show the same result.